# Display groupFooterTemplate as the entire footer row for Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to display the groupFooterTemplate value when showing group aggregates to take the entire row? So instead of the content being confined to the single column where you put the groupFooterTemplate property, I'd like for it to take up the entire row so the contents don't wrap if the container column is really small.

Using the Kendo template to add a tr seems to add a completely new, separate row and also another blank one, so that doesn't work. I also tried targeting the affected td to give it a colspan, but since the grid automatically creates blank cells for the other columns, that didn't work either.

I feel like I'm missing something to be able to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a CSS solution for it, so it just overflows and makes it look like it takes the whole row.

```
.k-group-footer {
  td {
    overflow: visible;

    // div that contains the aggregate content
    .footer-totals {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
}
```